Creating a multiline table using R Markdown
I want to create a multiline table with multiple data elements being reported for each record of my data frame.
I figured this out with the help of ChatGPT and this works well but it's not very flexible. I need to produce different versions of this for different projects.
Wondering if there are other methods, perhaps using kableExtra or flextable, that others might suggest.
---
title: "Multi-Line Table"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

# Sample data frame
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  Name = c("John", "Jane", "Tom", "Alice", "Bob"),
  Age = c(28, 34, 22, 29, 40),
  Profession = c("Engineer", "Doctor", "Artist", "Teacher", "Scientist")
)

# Function to create a multiline table for each row
create_row_table <- function(row_data) {
  table_text <- paste0(
    "| **Field**      | **Value**     |\n",
    "|:---------------|:--------------|\n",
    paste0(
      "| ID             | ", row_data$ID, "             |\n",
      "| Name           | ", row_data$Name, "         |\n",
      "| Age            | ", row_data$Age, "          |\n",
      "| Profession     | ", row_data$Profession, "  |\n"
    )
  )
  return(table_text)
}
```
#Render table
```{r table, results = 'asis'}
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  cat(create_row_table(data[i, ]), "\n\n\\newpage\n")
}
```

